# SWT Snippet2. Table sorting. items array changes in the loop. How does this work?

Tags: java, sorting, swt, code-snippets

> http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet2.java

I am trying in SWT to add sorting to a table widget. Copying the code from Snippet2 `sortListener` Handler doesn't work.  It correctly swaps two items into sorted order. More than 2 items in the table, and the results are unpredictable.

It seems to me  (in the following code extract from Snippet2 `sortListener`) that `items[i].dispose()` is going to change the array of `TableItems` called items that we are iterating over in the outer for loop, `for (int i = 1 ......`  Also, when one item is `disposed()`, and inserted into items at a new index, the whole array is recreated afresh.  That surely breaks the iteration?

So, I guess I have two questions:

1. What am I not understanding about Snippet2's algorithm?
2. Is there any other obvious reason why a sort operation might return random results (bearing in mind I am a noob, so am likely to have made the stupidest of mistakes)?

Here is my code:

```
Listener sortListener = new Listener() {
    public void handleEvent(Event e) {
        TableItem[] items = table.getItems();
        Collator collator = Collator.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
        TableColumn column = (TableColumn)e.widget;
        int index = column == column1 ? 0 : 1;
        for (int i = 1; i < items.length; i++) {                <--------- HERE
            String value1 = items[i].getText(index);
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++){
                String value2 = items[j].getText(index);
                if (collator.compare(value1, value2) < 0) {
                    String[] values = {items[i].getText(0), items[i].getText(1)};
                    items[i].dispose();                         <--------- HERE
                    TableItem item = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE, j);
                    item.setText(values);
                    items = table.getItems();                   <--------- HERE

                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        table.setSortColumn(column);
    }
};
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code or outputting the items array? I really think that would help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use JFace wrapper for SWT table ([org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TableViewer](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Fviewers%2FTableViewer.html)), which gives your table more built in features. I suggest this [tutorial for JFace TableViewer](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseJFaceTable/article.html). Here is [tutorial for sorting TableViewer](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseJFaceTableAdvanced/article.html#sortcolumns).

Answer (score 1):

This code snippet works for any number of items in the table (I tested it).
 
But it works only for 2 columns. (Is that your problem?)
If you have more columns in the table, the code would look like this:

```
    Listener sortListener = new Listener() {
        public void handleEvent(Event e) {
            TableItem[] items = table.getItems();
            Collator collator = Collator.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
            TableColumn column = (TableColumn)e.widget;
            int index = table.indexOf(column);
            for (int i = 1; i < items.length; i++) {             //   <--------- HERE
                String value1 = items[i].getText(index);
                for (int j = 0; j < i; j++){
                    String value2 = items[j].getText(index);
                    if (collator.compare(value1, value2) < 0) {
                        String[] values = new String[table.getColumnCount()];
                        for (int columnIdx = 0; columnIdx < table.getColumnCount(); 
                                columnIdx++){
                            values[columnIdx] = items[i].getText(columnIdx);
                        }
                        items[i].dispose();                      //   <--------- HERE
                        TableItem item = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE, j);
                        item.setText(values);
                        items = table.getItems();                //   <--------- HERE

                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            table.setSortColumn(column);
        }
    };
```